# Live Video Streaming From one android device to other android device over wifi

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

**Through below code i am starting video streaming from one device and its running successfully**

```
// Begin video communication
                            final ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(client);

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                                    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                                    recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
                                   // recorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
                                    recorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
                                    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
                                    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
                                    try {
                                        recorder.prepare();
                                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    try {

                                        recorder.start();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Video recorder3.3333 " + e);
                                    }
```

---

**Through below code i am playing video streaming on second device**

```
clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP), SERVERPORT);

                                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(clientSocket);
                                pfd.getFileDescriptor().sync();

                                pfd.close();
                                mp.setDisplay(holder);
                                mp.prepareAsync();
                                mp.start();
```

but problem on this line `// pfd.getFileDescriptor().sync();`

i got error:

> java.io.SyncFailedException: fsync failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

what is the solution for this?